# Can the error variance for an item in CFA be > 1?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I am doing a CFA for 5 constructs, and all together having 23 items, and each construct having a  minimum of 3 items each. The error variance of two items are 1.21 and 1.08. How can the error variance be more than 1?

Comment: Presumably that's not the standardized error variance. So it can be any (positive) value.

Comment: However, your question is unclear. The title says it's a factor, the details say it's an item. Which is it?

Comment: The error variance for the item (For example e1) Thanks Jeremy

Comment: Also can you use this unstandardiszed error variance value in computing the construct reliability?

Comment: Yes, you can. Google composite reliability.